# Order matrix by column with python

Tags: python

I have this matrix:

```
[[1, 0.7142857142857144], [3, 3.7142857142857144]]
```

And I need order that matrix by second column in desc order using python, How can I do it?

Comment: the second column needs to be sorted or how do you mean ?

Comment: I need order and result should be:
[[3, 3.7142857142857144], [1, 0.7142857142857144]]

Comment: `sorted(matrix, key=lambda row: row[1], reverse=True)`

Comment: Thanks @Aran-Fey, it's work!